Can you turn off the annoying tool panel that pops up when selecting an object in "edit PDF" mode in Adobe Acrobat Pro?
In my job as a patent attorney, I sometimes use Adobe Acrobat Pro to make my own quick edits to patent drawings prepared by an illustrator using their own software (likely Adobe Illustrator, Inkscape or similar). I may move, delete, stretch, or copy and paste vector objects.
In a recent update, Adobe has made it so that when I select an object in this mode, a tool panel pops up with options to crop, rotate, delete, export, replace, or redact the selected object, right next to the object, sometimes on top of the bounding box of the object so that I can't grab the handle I want, and even more often covering the environment of the object.
My question is simple - is there an option to stop this tool panel from popping up, or to have it pop up in a corner of the viewing frame somewhere out of the way?


Edit -> Preferences -> General -> unclick "Show Quick Actions on Text Selection"
Then click Ok.
